# How AEM syncs the osgi configuration changes made via felix console and from repository?

Tags: osgi, aem, osgi-bundle

If I change any  osgi configuration in felix web console it will be saved under path apps/system/config by default. How can we change this location?

If I change the osgi configuration (modified a property or added new a property ) for a PID after creating sling:OsgiConfig type node under /apps/my-project/config . These changes will be synced to apps/system/config and vice versa?

After modification either by any of two methods, finally the configuration stored under both locations(i.e apps/system/config and /apps/my-project/config/xxxx (of node type sling:OsgiConfig))  will be same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AEM won't ever sync that for you.
To make it work properly you have to create the config under your custom location `/apps/my-project/config` *prior* to making any changes in configMgr. Only then the changes made in configMgr will be reflected in that custom directory because the OSGI will bind the config properly to your /apps/my-project/config.

If you make changes in configMgr prior to creating this your custom `/apps/my-project/config` then the config will be bound to /apps/system/config and you're doomed. you need to delete in crx/de the related files from /apps/system/config

You might also need to delete the related config in crx-quickstart:

`\crx-quickstart\launchpad\config\..some further path`

and restart the instance.
numerous times in combination with previous steps.

Comment: thanks for clarification.  Changing osgi cofigurations in custom file  and felix console needs restarting of bundle to changes reflect?